# Javascript - nested loops and indexes

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to build an array that should look like this :

```
[
 [{"name":"Mercury","index":0}],
 [{"name":"Mercury","index":1},{"name":"Venus","index":1}],
 [{"name":"Mercury","index":2},{"name":"Venus","index":2},{"name":"Earth","index":2}],
...
]
```

Each element is the concatenation of the previous and a new object, and all the indexes get updated to the latest value (e.g. Mercury's index is 0, then 1, etc.). 
I have tried to build this array using the following code :

```
var b = [];
var buffer = [];
var names = ["Mercury","Venus","Earth"]
for (k=0;k<3;k++){

    // This array is necessary because with real data there are multiple elements for each k
    var a = [{"name":names[k],"index":0}]; 

    buffer = buffer.concat(a);

    // This is where the index of all the elements currently in the 
    // buffer (should) get(s) updated to the current k 
    for (n=0;n<buffer.length;n++){
        buffer[n].index = k;
    }

    // Add the buffer to the final array
    b.push(buffer);

}
console.log(b);
```

The final array (b) printed out to the console has the right number of objects in each element, but all the indexes everywhere are equal to the last value of k (2). 
I don't understand why this is happening, and don't know how to fix it.

Comment: I have to ask - _why_ do you need the data in this particular format?   The `.index` property is just equal to the outer array offset plus one.

Comment: In the data I'm using index is replaced by arbitrary years, which cannot be inferred from the length of the array. Plus, I wanted to understand this seemingly weird behavior...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is happening because every object in the inner array is actually the exact same object as the one stored in the previous outer array's entries - you're only storing *references* to the object, not copies.  When you update the `index` in the object you're updating it everywhere.

To resolve this, you need to create new objects in each inner iteration, or use an object copying function such as ES6's `Object.assign`, jQuery's `$.extend` or Underscore's `_.clone`.

Here's a version that uses the first approach, and also uses two nested `.map` calls to produce both the inner (variable length) arrays and the outer array:

```
var names = ["Mercury","Venus","Earth"];

var b = names.map(function(_, index, a) {
    return a.slice(0, index + 1).map(function(name) {
        return {name: name, index: index};
    });
});
```

or in ES6:

```
var names = ["Mercury","Venus","Earth"];
var b = names.map((_, index, a) => a.slice(0, index + 1).map(name => ({name, index})));
```

Comment: E.g., you're storing several different *arrays* (thanks to `concat` returning a new array), but each of them contains references to the objects (not copies of the objects).

Comment: @Alnitak : Thanks, the first solution works as expected. I'm not familiar with .map() though. Could you please explain the meaning of the "_" in the first callback function ?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder : thanks for the clarification, I inded thought that because I was creating a new array all the content was copied.

Comment: @GuitarExtended `.map` is the canonical function to transmute one array into another array.  I used the `_` as a convention to indicate an unused parameter.  Re: the arrays themselves, only the (invisible) _references_ are copied.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var names = ["Mercury","Venus","Earth"];
var result = [];
for (var i=0; i<names.length; i++){
  var _temp = [];
  for(var j=0; j<=i; j++){
    _temp.push({
      name: names[j],
      index:i
    });
  }
  result.push(_temp);
}

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this simple script:

```
var b = [];
var names = ["Mercury","Venus","Earth"];
for(var pos = 0; pos < names.length; pos++) {
    var current = [];
    for(var x = 0; x < pos+1; x++) {
        current.push({"name": names[x], "index": pos});
    }
    b.push(current);
}
```

Comment: this code is semantically identical to that in Rajesh's answer from 10 minutes before